# An in-depth introduction to TikZ graphs beside the official manual

Tags: tikz-pgf, books

When I first started learning TikZ I found the following introductions extremely helpful:

1. *A very minimal introduction to TikZ* by Jacques Crémer
2. *TikZ pour l'impatient* (in French) by Gérard Tisseau and Jacques Duma

However, neither of these documents cover the subject of TikZ graphs*, and, while the official manual is well-written, I find its description of graphs a little difficult to follow on a first reading.

Besides the manual, is there a good introduction out there to TikZ graphs, preferably one that covers the subject in depth?

---

* I'm referring to graphs in the sense of 'graph theory', not in the sense of 'the graph of a function f:R->R'.

Comment: If you want a general approach for all possible kinds of graphs, use the official manual. Else: You need to define which graphs you are interested in.

Comment: Pgfplots may be useful to you.

Comment: @TeXnician: I was referring to general graphs.

Comment: @JPi: In what way?

Comment: These aren't in great detail, but do summarize the implementation of graph drawing in TikZ. Moreover, they are written by the author of TikZ. Tantau, T. (2013). Graph drawing in TikZ. Journal of Graph Algorithms and Applications 17(4), 495–513. DOI: 10.7155/jgaa.00301
Tantau, T. (2013), Graph drawing in TikZ. In Didimo, W. and Patrignani, M. International Symposium on Graph Drawing. (GD 2012) Springer-Verlag pp517-528. DOI: 10.1007/978-3-642-36763-2_46.

Comment: Well, if you like drawing plots of functions, it can be convenient.  Like @TeXnician said, it depends on what kind of graphs you want to draw.

Comment: @JPi: O, I see. You're right. But I meant graphs in the sense of graph theory, not in the sense of the graph of a function f:R->R.

Comment: In that case, this offers some examples: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/graphs/

Comment: A guy called Jannis Pohlman did a lot of development of the Lua-based graphdrawing library for his diploma thesis (he was supervised by Till Tantau), which is available at http://www.tcs.uni-luebeck.de/downloads/papers/2011/2011-configurable-graph-drawing-algorithms-jannis-pohlmann.pdf Is that more theoretical than what you had in mind?

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: It might be too theoretical, but I'll take a look. Thanks.